# Unit test function that return value from database

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit

Currently i want to create unit test to cover some function in my developed feature, but i a have problem when facing this kind of function, when the purpose of function is to retrieve result from database.

```php
public function saveMessage($request)
    {
        $validation = $this->validate($request);

        if($validation['status']) {
            $input = $validation['detail'];

            $data = [
                'id'            => $input['id'],
                'note'          => $input['message'],
                'create_by'     => $input['create_by'],
                'status'        => $input['status'],
                'create_date'   => DATETIME,
            ];

            $result = $this->fooService->insert($data);

            return [
                'success' => true
            ];
        }
        return $validation;
    }
```

Is it possible to cover this kind of function without touching database ?

Comment: sure, you can mock the `fooService` (potentially), but what are you actually going to be testing for?

Comment: This seems a better candidate for an integration test. Unit tests shouldn't deal with code that performs actions on the infrastructure level.

Comment: Like El_Vanja said. If you want to tset if the values are stored in the db, better user an integration test. If you really want a unit test, mock out the DB like lagbox suggested

Comment: Alright, i got the point. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a unit test, you should mock whole dependency of the method otherwise it will become integration test.

I used to mock with [Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) (deprecated soon from phpunit 10) but you can use MockBuilder it is same principle, an example if you want to mock `$this->fooService`:

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    $this->fooService = $this->prophesize(FooService::class);
    $this->classOfMethodToTest = new ClassOfMethodToTest(
        $this->fooService->reveal()
    ); // mock FooService dependency
}

public function testSaveMessage(): void
{
    $this->fooService
        ->insert(Argument::type('array')) // or an real array
        ->shouldBeCalledOnce() // apparently it is called only once
        ->willReturn(true) // for example i don't know real logic
    ;
    
    $this->classOfMethodToTest->saveMessage($fakeData);
}
```

Comment: Good answer but I recommend 100% to use [Mockery](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mocking#mocking-objects) instead of Prophecy.